# How to test significant differences?

Tags: statistics, data-analysis

I have a model that generates results based on simulation with different settings. Now I want to know if it does really matter what settings I use. I have a single column of results, one result for each different settings. How can I test if there is a significant difference between the results?

For example:
[column 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtssC.png)

I looked at t-test, but I need a H_0, for that, and that is not applicable in my case.

Comment: Does each model generate a random result, and you have only one sample, or every model generates a predictable result and if you re-run it you get the same result? If the latter, there is no point in testing a statistical hypothesis about this, because the probability that model $2$ produced a different result than model $1$ *by chance* is zero. Instead, you should concentrate on mathematically modelling what "matters" to you. For example, if it matters for you that the model produces a result close to $0.3$, then none of the models are good and you should throw them all away.

Comment: (Cont'd) If the former, then why not collect a number of results so that you can estimate the expectation and variance of those, to start with?

Comment: Thank you for your input. The outcome per setting is kind of random, although, if I run the same setting twice, the outcome is the same. I need to know if it matters what settings I use to generate the results. Maybe it is better to see what the variance is of the ourcomes than, and if I consider that variance acceptible?